# Python 3.8: Recursively reading a dictionary with value of list into multiple class instances while also creating those instances in the recursion

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, recursion, instance

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, ID=0, Make = "", Model = "", Status = "", Price = 0, ServiceDate = ""):
        self.ID = ID
        self.Make = Make
        self.Model = Model
        self.Status = Status
        self.Price = Price
        self.ServiceDate = ServiceDate
```

```
MainDictionary = {
1167234: ['Apple ', 'phone', 'damaged', 534, [2, 1, 2022]], 
2390112: ['Dell', 'laptop', '', 799, [7, 2, 2020]], 
9034210: ['Dell', 'tower', '', 345, [5, 27, 2020]], 
7346234: ['Lenovo', 'laptop', 'damaged', 239, [9, 1, 2021]], 
3001265: ['Samsung', 'phone', '', 1200, [12, 1, 2023]], 
2347800: ['Apple ', 'laptop', '', 999, [7, 3, 2020]], 
1009453: ['Lenovo', 'tower', '', 599, [10, 1, 2021]]}
```

My goal is to recursively:
1.) create a class instance for each key value pair in the dictionary
2.) fill that instance with the key and list items in the value list into their corresponding class instance attribute
3.) read the newly created and populated class instances back into a list

I cannot comprehend how to create new instances of the class recursively to allow me to read in the key and values into separate class instances. The code I have below runs but it is only creating one class instance and overwriting that instance every time it loops resulting in one class instance, with the correct format, for the last item in the dictionary instead of multiple class instances, one for each dictionary entry.

```
for key, value in MainDictionary.items():
     AnotherInstance = Item(key, value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4])
```

After creating all the class instances I would read them into a list to be able to easily reference them later.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
classesList = []
for key, value in MainDictionary.items():
     classesList.append(Item(key, value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4]))
```